# ArcGIS Online symbols disappear

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online

I uploaded my own symbols to use in the legend of my map.

However, after I refresh the map some of the symbols will disappear. And each time after that I refresh the map, more symbols disappear. Right now I just have the symbols saved in a folder under "My Content" tab.

Do I need to use another online source in order for them to save correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your image public and then use the url provided in the item details of the image that ends in /data in the symbol editor.